# Frobenius Method Quesion

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

Solving for $x^2y^{''}+4xy^{'}-(x^2-2)y=0$ for homework, I cannot figure out how to find the necessary $y_2$.

$$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{n+r},
y^{'}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(n+r) x^{n+r-1},
y^{''}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(n+r)(n+r-1)x^{n+r-2}
$$
Plugging these into the inital ODE:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+r-1)(n+r)a_nx^{n+r} + 4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+r)a_nx^{n+r} - \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_{n-2}x^{n+r} + 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n+r} \\
(r-1)(r)+4r+2=0, r=-1,2 \\
$$

$$
(r-1)(r)a_0+(r)(r+1)a_1+4r_0+4(r+1)a_1+2a_0+2a_1=0 \\
let\ r=-1, a_1=0\\
\\
a_n = \frac{a_{n-2}}{n(n+1)}\ for\ n\geq 2\\
$$
let $$a_0=1, n=2, a_2 = \frac{1}{3!}\\
n=3, a_3 = 0\\
n=4, a_4 = \frac{1}{5!}\\
\vdots\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}\\
$$
From here, $$y_1 = x^{-1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(2n+1)!}$$

However, I cannot figure out how to move forward to find $y_2$ using reduction of order or 'manually'.

Wolframalpha provides a different answer, alas I'm not sure how: $y(x) = (c_1 e^{-x})/x^2 + (c_2 e^x)/x^2$

Comment: @LutzLehmann Formatting error, oops. I have the initial equation. Is it fine now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r^2+3r+2=0$ has solutions $r=-1,-2$.

The equation after that is not wrong but unclear, where does it come from?

You should be careful with the indices, what you computed is $a_{2n}=\frac1{(2n+1)!}$. Then $y_1(x)=x^{-2}\sinh(x)$.

You could try to do the same for the solution with $r=-2$ and should get $y_2(x)=x^{-2}\cosh(x)$, which gives and alternative but equivalent basis to the WA solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. The equation comes adding up the sums until n=2 for the first, second, and fourth part of the sums. So, letting n=0, and n=1. How did you 'convert' a_2n into y_1 in this case?

Comment: You get correctly $y_1(x)=x^{-1}\sum_n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}=x^{-2}\sum_n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=x^{-2}\sinh(x)$.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!